# jdbcTemplate#query gives back only the first row instead of all

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following code in my app and for some reason the rowMapper (`rs.toWord()`) is called only once with the first id and the others are ignored.

If I run the query manually with a mysql client it works perfectly. I double checked and the namedParameters are generated properly.

Do you have any idea why the query will not give back all the results?

```
    val sql = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE id IN (:wordsInSentence)"
    val namedParameters = mapOf("wordsInSentence" to wordsInSentence.joinToString(separator = ","))
    val words = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters) { rs: ResultSet, _ ->
        rs.toWord()
    }
```

Comment: Could you show toWord method?

Comment: I would presume `wordsInSentence.joinToString` returns a single `String`, as it looks like it joins a bunch of them together with a comma?

Comment: I fixed it by changing namedParameters to string concatenation. But I would like to know why it wasn't working? If I don't use the namedParams but use     val sql = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE id IN ($wordsInSententenceJoinedByComma)" instead of :wordsInSentence then it works...